# MariaDB Query using EXISTS() function does not work inside function body

Tags: sql, mariadb

I'm trying to check if a routine exists, using this query:

```sql
select exists(select 1 from information_schema.ROUTINES where ROUTINE_NAME = $name_of_routine);
```

It works. So I wrapped it in a function:

```sql
create
    definer = MES_DHSol@`%` function fn_routine_exists($name_of_routine varchar(64)) returns tinyint(1)
begin
    return exists(select 1 from information_schema.ROUTINES where ROUTINE_NAME = $name_of_routine);
end;
```

So I can use it like this:

```sql
select fn_routine_exists('sp_result');
```

However, it gives me an error:

```
[22003][1264] Out of range value for column 'CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH' at row 1
```

### Workarounds

I've made it working, making no use of `EXISTS()`.

```sql
create
    definer = MES_DHSol@`%` function fn_routine_exists($name_of_routine varchar(64)) returns tinyint(1)
begin
    declare v_exists tinyint(1) default false;

    select true
    from information_schema.ROUTINES
    where ROUTINE_NAME = $name_of_routine
    into v_exists;
    
    return v_exists;
end;
```

Still wondering why using `EXISTS()` inside function makes that error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a bug.

You've got some procedure/function that returns more than the 2G for the [information_schema.ROUTINES](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/information-schema-routines-table/) CHARACTER_MAXIMUM_LENGTH field and somehow this only triggers in a routine.

I've been unable to reproduce this on the latest 10.3, 10.4 or 10.6 with a function returning a longblob (which should have a 4G result, but it got truncated).

Please create [new bug report](https://jira.mariadb.org) including the MariaDB version and the function header of `sp_result`, and `select * from information_schema.ROUTINES where ROUTINE_NAME='sp_result';` if possible.